# WP Rest API max limit include parameter?

Tags: wp-query, wp-api, rest-api

I'm using the rest API to get only selected posts though Rest API. I have used `include=<ids>` parameter.

I have send the API request like:

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=11,12`

It works as expected. But, What happen If there are 200+ post IDs.

The request like:

`http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=11,12,...,200`

What is the max limit for `include` parameter? I have used the `POST` method to get the posts.

Comment: Are you trying to get all posts or just specific ones? if you want all posts then remove the ?include... part and just end the call at /posts

Comment: Nope, I'm want a specific posts. For that I have used `include`. I think I need to send more request (100 each) to get all the posts. It'll be helpful.

Comment: If you want a specific post, then do this: /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/11 - I've checked the wordpress rest api handbook and they don't show a way to get multiple posts using "?include".  That only lets you get one post, not a group of posts.  You could categorize or tag the posts to get a group.

Comment: In a handbook the `include` parameter is not listed. I have used it to get the group of posts by ids. Check this example https://www.nprdpinc.org/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?include=200,3477 you'll get only 2 posts.

I'll categorize the posts but, The reasons of `include` parameter is, I have import the posts with rest API and once imported the id of that post is stored in the option table. 

So, I have showing the imported posts to user with the help of stored post ids and using `include` parameter in the rest api.

Comment: I have check the Rest API class and found that the parameter `include` is mapping parameter of `post__in`. You can see here other mapping parameters. 
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9/src/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L170

Comment: I have created the article of all possible query parameter mappings - https://maheshwaghmare.wordpress.com/2018/06/12/wordpress-rest-api-query-parameters-mappings/

Comment: Going back to your original question.  I'm not sure if i would want to request 200 posts in a URL.  That doesn't seem very attractive.  The url is going to be super long and cumbersome.  It'll be prettier if you use a category or tag to get all 200 posts. IMO.